# How to generate two different version source code at the same time

Tags: build, makefile, qt-creator

I'm using QtCreator 2.8.0 qt 4.8.1
I have a program but two versions of it and have a variable to control.like that:

`if(var==version1){/*...*/}else{/*...*/}`

In the main function:

`var=version1`

Some of the function are shared.It's boring build everyone of them,How can I build both of them at the same time?
I've read [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725542/msbuild-how-to-make-several-builds-with-different-versions-from-same-sources) .

Answer (score 0):

In your Makefile have a target setup like this:

```
both: version1 version2

version1: 
  # commands to compile version 1

version2: 
  # commands to compile version 2
```

then you can just do

```
% make both
```

Technically this is called making a dependency, but it gives the effect you appear to want.

Comment: A variable means it has many statements like: if(var==version1){/*...*/}else{/*...*/} and "var=version1;" at the begin of main function.Your solution can't meet my problem.

Comment: Ok, i think i understand more now. I think you want 2 different versions of main. Put them in different directories, and us the my makefile idea to Include whichever one is needed.